# I keep getting the error "The variable 'b' is being used without being initialized, and I'm not sure how to fix it

Tags: c++

```
//Benjamin McKinney
//CSCI 2010-10
//Spring 2015
//PASS 3

//Programmed on Windows 8.1 using Visual C++ 2010 Express

//This program plays the game MasterMind

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct Player
{
    string Name;
    int HighScores[6];
    bool CheatOn;
};

struct Board
{
    int NumHoles;
    int Holes[6];
};

struct Guess
{
    int Count;
    int NumHoles;
    int Holes;
};

void printHighScores(string);
void readHighScore(string);
void updateHighScore(string, int);
string getPlayer();
int getBoard();
void playGame(string);
void menu(string);

int main()
{
    Player p;
    srand((unsigned int)time(0));

    cout << "!!! Benjamin McKinney's Master-MasterMind!!!\n";
    cout << "--------------------------------------------\n";

    getPlayer();
    menu(p.Name);

    cout << "Goodbye, " << p.Name << endl;
    printHighScores(p.Name);

    cout << "----------------------------------------------\n";
    cout << "!!! Benjamin McKinney's Master-MasterMind!!!\n";

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

void printHighScores(string name)
{
    return;
}

void readHighScore(string)
{
    return;
}

void updateHighScore(string, int)
{
    return;
}

string getPlayer()
{
    Player p;
    cout << "What is your name?\n";
    cin >> p.Name;
    cout << "Welcome, " << p.Name << endl;
    p.CheatOn = false;
    readHighScore(p.Name);
    return p.Name;
}

int getBoard()
{
    Board b;

    cout << "Enter the number of holes you would like: ";
    cin >> b.NumHoles;

    if(b.NumHoles > 6 || b.NumHoles < 1)
    {   
        cout << "Error! You must pick a number between 1 and 6! Try again!\n";
    }

    for(int i=0;i<b.NumHoles;i++)
    {
        b.Holes[i] = rand() % 2 + 1;
    }

    return b.NumHoles;
}

void playGame(string)
{
    Player p;
    Board b;
    Guess g;
    getBoard();

    g.Count=0;

    for(int i=0;i<b.NumHoles;i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter your guess for the row\n";
        if(p.CheatOn == true)
        {
            for(int a=0;a<(sizeof(b.Holes)-1);a++)
            {
                cout << b.Holes[a];
            }
        }
        cout << "Enter your guess for hole " << i << ": ";
        cin >> g.Holes;
        g.Count++;
    }

    return;
}

void menu(string)
{
    Player p;
    char choice;

    cout << "Please choose an option below:\n";
    cout << "\t P)lay\n\t Q)uit\n\tChoice: ";
    cin >> choice;

    if(choice == 'P')
        playGame(p.Name);
    else
        if(choice == 'Q')
            return;
        else`enter code here`
            if(choice == 'C')
            {
                p.CheatOn = true;
                playGame(p.Name);
            }
}
```

Ignore the three HighScore functions, but otherwise I can't get this to work... "Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'b' is being used without being initialized." is the main issue that I'm having. If anyone can help me I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Read up on variable scope.

Comment: The `Board b` in `getBoard()` is not the same as in `playGame()`... the same goes for `Player` that you instantiate multiple times.

Comment: I instantiated them because I couldn't pass them through. I've tried every way I can think of, and can't get it to work. @jpw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `playGame` function:

```
void playGame(string)
{
    Player p;
    Board b;         // <----- uninitialized
    // ...
    for(int i=0;i<b.NumHoles;i++)
    //            ^^^^^^^^^^
```

you use `b.NumHoles` when you have never initialized `b`.

I guess you intended that `getBoard()` would magically have some effect on `b` but it doesn't. The `getBoard` function updates a local board but never does anything with it.

To fix this you could change `getBoard` to return the whole board:

```
Board getBoard()
{
    Board b;
    // set up b...
    return b;
}
```

and then inside `playGame`:

```
Board b = getBoard();
```

---

There's another error just below:

```
for(int a=0;a<(sizeof(b.Holes)-1);a++)
```

The `sizeof` operator gives the size *in bytes*. You actually want the size in elements, so you need to divide by the element size:

```
a < (sizeof b.Holes / sizeof b.Holes[0])
```

I'm not sure what the `-1` was meant to be doing either, this would just cause you to not output the last hole.

Comment: Thanks! That worked! I appreciate it, I was getting to the point where I was about to just chuck my computer through the wall... So you saved its life.